# How to keep agent's temp folder in order to invoke command from Azure DevOps release pipeline manually

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I want to troubleshot a single step from Azure DevOps release pipeline (classic mode).

The step invokes similar command on deployment VM:

```
C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tool\VsTest\17.0.0\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@_work\_temp\qrjwcoj0moy.tmp
```

However the temp folder `C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\` is removed. Can I keep keep the temp files in order to invoke the command manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml (check "Agent.TempDirectory") it is not possible because temp folder is cleaned after each pipeline job.

If you want to keep these files you need to copy them (task: CopyFiles) to different folder before job ends to be able to check them later.

Answer (score 3):

I have added a step that copies the directory depending on the variable 'system.debug':

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AgentTempDirectory'
  displayName: 'Copy Agent.TempDirectory to drop'
  condition: eq(variables['system.debug'], 'true')
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [answer by @PainElemental](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73061665/5664960), here's how to publish the temp directory as an artifact for debugging:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Agent.TempDirectory'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    artifact: TempDirectory
  condition: eq(variables['system.debug'], 'true')
```

Note that passwords or other secrets that are read from e.g. variable groups may be included *in plaintext* in the published scripts. At least for PowerShell scripts that was the case for me.